# Error estimation for splines in polynomial interpolation

Tags: calculus, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

[Please click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NHZ8.png)

At the bottom part, why is it 1/8 and not 1/2 ? With n=1. Even if n was =2, we would still have 1/6.. what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the interpolating spline is linear in this case. Let $s_i(x)$ be the $i$th piece of the spline, and let $f_i$ be the restriction of $f$ to this interval.

From the (Lagrange) error formula for interpolation, we know
$$
 f_i(x) - s_i(x)  = \frac{f''(\xi)}{2} (x - x_{i+1})(x-x_i)
$$
so that 
\begin{align*}|f_i(x) - s_i(x)| 
&\le  \left\vert \frac{ (x - (x_{i+1}))(x- x_i)}{2} \right\vert  \max \limits_{\xi \in [x_i,x_{i+1}]} |f''(\xi)| \\
& = \left\vert \frac{ (x - (x_i + h_i))(x- x_i)}{2} \right\vert  \max \limits_{\xi \in [x_i,x_{i+1}]} |f''(\xi)|
\end{align*}

Now, use elementary calculus to verify that $g(x)= (x - (x_i + h_i))(x- x_i)$ has a local extrema at the point $x_i + \frac{h_i}{2}$ with corresponding output $-h_i^2/4$.

Comment: Isn't Lagrange error formula only valid when we use the polynomials of degrees at most equal $n-1$ when we interpolate at $n$ point? Is true, then for a spline which interpolate between two points, this only valid for a linear interpolating polynomials $s_i(x)$, no?  What about the error when $s_i(x)$ are of some power $n$? Thank you.